# What is the difference between `::` and `@` in f#?

Tags: list, f#

I tried to add an additional item to my string list. I first thought to add the item to my list with `::`.

```
let test = ["hello"];;
let newtest = test :: ["world"];;
```

This threw me the error:

```
  let newtest = test :: ["world"];;
  -----------------------^^^^^^^

stdin(36,24): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'string list'    
but here has type
    'string'
```

It only started to work with `@`.
However, on several SO questions to create a new list the `::` method is used.
In order to use the `::`, I ended up creating a list of lists which is definitely not what I was looking for.

```
let newtest01 = test :: [["world"]];;
val newtest01 : string list list = [["hello"]; ["world"]]
```

Can somebody please explain the difference between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `::` ('cons') operator is used to build lists by prepending (or consing) an item to an existing list.
The `@` ('append') operator is used to concatenate two lists. You should read [this topic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists).

```
> let test = ["hello"];;
val test : string list = ["hello"]

> let newTest1 = "world" :: test;;
val newTest1 : string list = ["world"; "hello"]

> let newTest2 = test @ ["world"];;
val newTest2 : string list = ["hello"; "world"]
```